# Error using DialogResult.OK in OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, openfiledialog

I copied a OpenFileDialog from one of my other projects but it does not work on the new project.

```
 OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
        open.Filter = "Binary|*.bin";
        open.RestoreDirectory = true;
        open.Multiselect = false;
        try
        {
            if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
               //some code
            }
        }...
```

The Error says that I'm missing a reference.
So i tried to configure the references, but when i click the checkbox for System.Windows.Forms it says that I can not use it because the ActiveX-Library was importet from a .NET-Assembly and that it can not be added. In my previous project i added the reference and everything works fine. How can i add a reference to a .NET-Assembly?

*Bonus: Why is this happening? Is there any reason why adding a reference should be blocked within VisualStudio?*

-Edit- It is a WPF-App and I am using VisualStudio 2017 with .NET Framework 4.5.2

Comment: Project type? Framework version?

Comment: May be you are copying from a winfrom application. Go wpf way http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/dialogs/the-openfiledialog/

Comment: No i checked that. It is the same application. @Harsh

Comment: Then why are you referencing windows form open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK

Comment: Because it works in the other project. I just thought i can recycle my code.

Comment: @Thomas What he meant is that in WinForms, it uses the `DialogResult`, but in WPF, it doesn't, and requires a Boolean to check against the dialog being there, because of what WPF passes back out of the `Window` object you are using for your dialog.  So even though you can reference `System.Windows.Forms` in WPF, it doesn't matter, because of the `Window` object not passing back a `DialogResult`, but a Boolean to say it's alive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try replacing the winform reference with false.

Change this

```
if (open.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
```

to this

```
if (open.ShowDialog() == true)
```

Comment: Works fine. Thank you!